# Как заставить Hibernate получать вложенные объекты одним запросом?

Tags: hibernate, java, proxy

День добрый!

Мэплю Хибернейтом класс, который содержит коллекцию объектов другого класса. Выглядит это примерно так

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Action> actions;
```

с той стороны идет

```
@ManyToOne()
private Manager owner;
```

Далее делаю Критериа-запрос для получения всех объектов-контейнеров (то есть class=Manager). И в логах вижу: Хибернейт сначала получает объекты-контейнеры, а затем для каждого из них делает спец-селект для получения вложенных коллекций, то есть выдает в базу select ... where id=container_id для каждого найденного ранее контейнера. Это мне кажется не очень оптимальным. Не лучше ли брать все вместе одним join-ом?
Отсюда возникает вопрос: **можно ли заставить Хибернейт брать все вложенные коллекции одним join-ом?**

Чтобы дважды не вставать, задам и еще вопросик: в моем примере, как видно, я использую Eager Fetch чтобы показать эти мои вложенные коллекции в jsp. Но я также пробовал делать Hibernate.initialize(containerObject OR List<containerobject>), но это не работает: LazyInitialization остается.

**Почему не работает Hibernate.initialize?** Я думал, что он как раз для таких случаев. Пробовал так же использовать мой спринговский hibernateTemplate.initialize() (через который, кстати, запускаю Критерии), результат тот же.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить к вашему полю:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

По второму вопросу:

> он говорит: No session or session was closed

Видимо, вы пытаетесь провести принудительную инициализацию, после того как закрываете сессию.

Comment: Я вообще сессию и не вижу т.к. делаю все через hibernateTemplate Спринга. Но вы наверное правы, сессия закрыта. Получается после этого прокси уже никакими способами не заполнить?